# pip installing Flask-Ask raises ModuleNotFound pip.req

Tags: python, pip, flask-ask

When I try to install Flask-Ask, I get the following error. How do I fix it?

```
$ pip install flask-ask
Collecting flask-ask
Using cached Flask-Ask-0.9.8.tar.gz (40 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\loz99\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\loz99\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kw14h5ho\\flask-ask\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\loz99\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kw14h5ho\\flask-ask\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\loz99\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kw14h5ho\flask-ask\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\loz99\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kw14h5ho\flask-ask\
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\loz99\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kw14h5ho\flask-ask\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has been [fixed](https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask/commit/75228cef16a6f2e135757475632f25ce3ef447fb) but that version was never released to PyPi.

You can try to install from github directly:

```
pip install https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask/archive/master.zip
```

Comment: This package requires python headers. Don't forget to: "apt-get install python3-dev"

Comment: Not working on Windows 10, python 3.8.
I don't understand why it requires Visual Studio, I'm running from cmd and using IntelliJ.

  Running setup.py install for cffi ... error
       Creating library build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\c\_cffi_backend.cp38-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\c\_cffi_backend.cp38-win32.exp
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

Comment: @Claudiu If you have another problem, please open a new question!

Comment: Sorry Klaus, usually when I try this, got closed with the reason that is duplicate. I tried to fall back to pip 9, update to pip 20, now I'll try to run it under linux! If it won't work i'll open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the list of dependencies I found. This may be useful to debug what your installation is missing. I am on Windows 10, Python 3.7.3

```
G:\Vid2\YTD>pip install git+https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git@v0.8.8
Collecting git+https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git@v0.8.8
  Cloning https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git (to revision v0.8.8) to c:\users\raman\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-mr_0oxnv
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git 'C:\Users\raman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-mr_0oxnv'
  Running command git checkout -q 8fa6aa052a8a4b5273cbcceb48e926b41dbe8a32
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask-Ask==0.8.8 from git+https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git@v0.8.8 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-p
ackages
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (19.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aniso8601 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (9.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (0.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyOpenSSL->Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask->Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.3->pyOpenSSL->Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.3->pyOpenSSL->Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (1.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.3->pyOpenSSL->Flask-Ask==0.8.8) (2.19)
Building wheels for collected packages: Flask-Ask
  Building wheel for Flask-Ask (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\raman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-y9row5ix\wheels\30\78\ac\......95909776
Successfully built Flask-Ask
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git@v0.8.8
```

Comment: Not working ... Windows 10, python 3.8

Collecting cryptography>=3.2 (from pyOpenSSL->Flask-Ask==0.8.8)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/77/461087a514d2e8ece1c975d8216bc03f7048e6090c5166bc34115afdaa53/cryptography-3.4.7.tar.gz (546kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 552kB 723kB/s
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cffi>=1.12 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cffi>=1.12

Comment: I said It worked *for me*.
It still works today (8 May 2021), for my Windows 10, Python 3.7.3
G:\Vid2\YTD>pip install git+https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git@v0.8.8
Collecting git+https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git@v0.8.8
  Cloning https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git (to revision v0.8.8) to c:\users\raman\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-mr_0oxnv
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git 'C:\Users\raman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-mr_0oxnv'
  Running command git checkout -q 8fa6aa052a8a4b5273cbc......
Please reconsider !

Comment: ...And, is  your problem with  pythonhosted.org  and you are confusing it with  github.com/johnwheeler/ solution?